# Write log function without math library?

Tags: c

Write the

```
function double mylog( double  y);
```

Which computes the natural logarithm of y when `y>0`.  Do this by summing the terms of the power series,

```
mylog( y ) = 2*( x + x^3/3 + x^5/5 + x^7/7 + x^9 /9 + … )
```

Sum the terms up to `x^151`. Notice that the parameter y is NOT the x of the power series. Before computing the power series, calculate x:

```
x = (y‐1)/(y+1)
```

Write the function to be side‐effect free (no I/O, no output, no globals). If `y<=0.0` then  `return 0`. (The actual math.h function does something better than this.) For example, for `mylog( 3 )`, `x = 2/5 = .4`
`mylog( 3 ) = 2*( 0.4 + 0.4^3/3 + 0.4^5/5 + 0.4^7/7 + 0.4^9/9 + … ) ≈ .8473`
Your loop can keep a variable xpow that builds up the increasing powers of x so you don’t need a nested loop for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double  mylog(double y)
{
double x = (y-1)/(y+3);
double sum = 1.0;
double xpow=x;

for(int n = 1; n <= 151; n++)
{

if(n%2!=0)
{

sum = sum + xpow/(double)n;
}
xpow = xpow * x;

 }    

 sum *= 2;

 return sum;
 }

 int main()
 {
double num;

printf("Enter Number ");
scanf("%lf", &num);

num = mylog(num);
printf("%lf \n", num);
system("pause");
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: Oh man, that reads like a textbook/assignment question that's just been C&Ped, and all of that without even adding formatting...

Comment: You should factor out the x's, so your function would be 2*x*(1+ x^2*(1/3 + x^2*(1/5 + x^2*(1/7 + x^2*(1/9 + ...)...), how many decimal places are you expecting if you go to x^151? You'll need more than doubles.

Answer (score 4):

There is [fastapprox library](https://github.com/romeric/fastapprox) which answers this very question and few more in [one C header file](https://github.com/romeric/fastapprox/blob/master/fastapprox/src/fastonebigheader.h):

Quoting from it:

```
static inline float 
fastlog2 (float x)
{
    union { float f; uint32_t i; } vx = { x };
    union { uint32_t i; float f; } mx = { (vx.i & 0x007FFFFF) | 0x3f000000 };
    float y = vx.i;
    y *= 1.1920928955078125e-7f;

    return y - 124.22551499f
             - 1.498030302f * mx.f 
             - 1.72587999f / (0.3520887068f + mx.f);
}

static inline float
fastlog (float x)
{
    return 0.69314718f * fastlog2 (x);
}
```

Comment: It also has many SSE versions of the functions.  Very useful indeed!